# How to inject NLog using Autofac in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac, nlog

I have an ASP.NET Webforms project that I've been recently converting to use Dependency Injection via Autofac. It has all been going well, that is until I tried to inject my NLog instances. I can't work out how to perform the equivalent of the static GetCurrentClassLogger() method calls with the property injected Logger object.

Here is my sample code illustrating the problem:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Web;

public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
  private static IContainerProvider containerProvider;

  public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
  {
    get { return containerProvider; }
  }

  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    Bootstrapper.RegisterInstances(builder);
    containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
  }
}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
using Autofac;

public static class Bootstrapper
{
  public static void RegisterInstances(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<MyTestModule>().As<IMyTestModule>().InstancePerRequest();
  }
}
```

**MyTestModule.cs**

```
using System;

public class MyTestModule : IMyTestModule
{
   // was previously: protected static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  private ILogger _logger;

  public MyTestModule(ILogger logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public void DoSomethingBad()
  {
    try
    {
        int z = 5 / 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Error!", ex);
    }
  }
}

public interface IMyTestModule
{
  void DoSomethingBad();
}
```

**PageBase.cs**

```
public abstract class PageBase : Page
{
  // was previously: protected static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

  public IMyTestModule MyTestModuleInstance { get; set; }
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : PageBase
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MyTestModuleInstance.DoSomethingBad();
  }
}
```

You can see in **PageBase.cs** and **MyTestModule.cs** I have commented out the previous static calls to create the NLog instance:

```
protected static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

They are now simply replaced with the Autofac dependency injected property like this:

```
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

This works in so much that the Logger object gets initialised to an instance of the logger.

How do I perform the equivalent of **LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()** ?

Is there something I need to do with NLog modules to achieve this? If there is I've not been able to find any specific examples. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the [AttachTocomponentRegistaration](http://autofac.org/apidoc/html/DB09DDBB.htm) of your Module:

```
public class AutofacLogInjectionModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
    {
        new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), (p, i) => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger())
    });
    }

}
```

And Register this module in your bootstrap:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacLogInjectionModule());
```