# Autofac with WebForms public property throws constructor exception

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac

I am trying to modify an existing WebForms application and would like to use Autofac. As far as I can tell, I've set up the application according to the documentation (http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#structuring-pages-and-user-controls-for-di).

**Web page code with a public property**

```
public partial class MyTestPage : Page
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //page load code here
```

**web.config**

```
<modules>
<add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
        static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
        {
            get { return _containerProvider; }
        }


    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();
        _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());

    }
```

When I try to load the page, Autofac throws this exception.

No constructors on type 'NLog.Logger' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

What am I missing here? Why is Autofac looking for a constructor instead of picking up the public property?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Autofac is trying to create an instance of `Logger` class to inject it to your `MyTestPage`. It tries using default, parameter-less constructor, which is unavailable. So the problem is not with your page, but with your logger registration.

I am not familiar to `NLog`, but according to tutorial, you are suppose to use `LogManager` to create instances of `Logger`, e.g.

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

or

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyClassName");
```

So you should change your registration to something like this (not tested):

```
builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()).As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();
```

As I mentioned above, I am not familiar with NLog, but I assume NLog `Logger` class implements `ILogger` interface.

EDIT:

[This](https://github.com/ziyasal/Autofac.Extras.NLog) module should handle what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That does solve the exception but it creates all loggers with the name of "global" which is not useful for logging. 

This puts me in the same situation as this related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443955/how-to-inject-nlog-using-autofac-in-asp-net-webforms). I've tried that approach in the answer to that question but it got me to the exception in this question.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here... Do you want to somehow set the logger class when resolving it?

Comment: Doing this without DI would look like this.  
`public partial class MyTestPage : Page {  
protected static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`  
 When the logger logs something, the logger name would be "MyTestPage ." So I need to inject it but have the GetCurrentClassLogger() executing in the context of the web page, not the context of the global.asax.cs.

Comment: I think this nuget package may solve your problems: https://github.com/ziyasal/Autofac.Extras.NLog. You should register `NLogModule`, as shown in documentation. You can check the source code, how this is handled - it's similar to the SO question you linked in your first comment. I've edited my answer.